# Analysis of binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I am  reading data structures and algorithms at following location.

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page191.html

For binary search code which is shown below

```
unsigned int SortedListAsArray::FindOffset (
    Object const& object) const
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = count - 1;

    while (left <= right)
    {
    int const middle = (left + right) / 2;

    if (object > *array [middle])
        left = middle + 1;
    else if (object < *array [middle])
        right = middle - 1;
    else
        return middle;
    }
    return count;
}
```

In analysis author mentioned as below

> In the worst case, the item sought is not in the sorted list. Specifically, the worst case occurs when the item sought is smaller than any item in the list because this case requires two comparisons in each iteration of the binary search loop. In the worst case,  `(ceiling(log n) + 2 )` iterations are required. Therefore, the running time of the FindOffset function is `2(ceiling(log n) + 2) * T(op < ) + O(log n)`, where `T(op <)`  represents the running time required to compare to Object instances.

My question on above analysis is that

1. How author has came up with `+ 2` in statement `(ceiling(log n) + 2 )`?
2. Other question why author is adding `O(log n)` in statement `2(ceiling(log n) + 2) * T(op < ) + O(log n)`?

Thanks!

Comment: To me it seems that the first `+2` should be a `+1` (but maybe I'm missing some crazy case). The `O(log n)` in the second expression is the cost of recursion. Even if `T(op <)` would be `0`, the algorithm takes logarithmic time, so that has to be incorporated in the formula.

Comment: @Vincent van der Weelle From my understanding there is no recurssion mentioned here Kindly elaborate

Comment: You're right. I meant the cost of narrowing down the search range. I see that as going down a binary search tree, hence the term "recursion". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think the `+ 2` there was a mistake. I ran the code and it runs about `log(n)` times for a growing input size `n`.